# How to convert a HTML table with `<td rowspan=2` to text or markdown?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to give LLM the content of html and ask it some questions.

It does not understand table with rows like `<td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc; border:3px solid #FFCD00;"><strong>880円</strong></td>` well enough, always gives wrong answer.

```
<table class="detailList col01" style="background-color:#fff;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="step" scope="col">
                <div class="text">データ定額<br>440プラン</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="text"><span class="linkTxt typeA"><a href="/domestic/service/vita" target="_blank"
                            class="bgBlue newWindow" rel="noopener noreferrer">ビタッ！<br>プラン</a></span></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="text"><span class="linkTxt typeA"><a href="/domestic/planlp_jiyujizai_super" target="_blank"
                            class="bgBlue newWindow" rel="noopener noreferrer">自由自在<br>プラン</a></span></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">Rakuten<br>最強プラン</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">ahamo</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">LINEMO</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">povo2.0</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-top:0; padding-top:0;">
            <th style="border-left:0;"></th>
            <th class="step" scope="col">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" colspan="8">月額基本料金</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～100MB<br>まで</th>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc;"><strong>440円</strong></td>
            <td><strong>198円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <div class="secBoxCompareBalloonCnt">
                    <p>100MB未満の月は<br><strong>290円！</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p><strong>550円～</strong></p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>1,078円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="8"><strong>2,970円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>990円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <div class="text">
                    <p><strong>390円</strong></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">7日間</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～1GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>770円</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～2GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc;"><strong>580円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>770円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>990円</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">30日間</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～3GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>1,320円</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～5GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc; border:3px solid #FFCD00;"><strong>880円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>990円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>2,178円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>2,728円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>2,700円</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">30日間</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～7GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>2,310円</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～10GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc; border:3px solid #FFCD00;"><strong>1,980円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>2,190円</strong><br>5分かけ放題付！</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～20GB</th>
            <td>15GBまで<br><strong>3,300円</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～30GB</th>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc;"><strong>4,980円</strong></td>
            <td><strong>5,775円</strong></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>5,990円</strong><br>5分かけ放題付！</td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>3,278円</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">パートナー回線エリアは最大1Mbpsで使い放題</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>4,950円</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">オプション<br>100GBまで</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">＋550円/1GB<br>で追加可</td>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>6,490円</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">60GB/<br>90日間</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">～50GB</th>
            <td style="background-color: #f7f7f7;">+330円/1GB<br>で追加可</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" colspan="8">通話料・オプション</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">回線</th>
            <td style="background-color:#ffffcc;">NTTドコモ</td>
            <td>NTTドコモ<br>ソフトバンク</td>
            <td>NTTドコモ</td>
            <td>楽天</td>
            <td>NTTドコモ</td>
            <td>ソフトバンク</td>
            <td>au</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">通話料</th>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffcc;">–</td>
            <td rowspan="2">–</td>
            <td><strong>9円/30秒</strong><br>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1"><strong>専用アプリ<br>不要</strong></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>22円/30秒</strong><br>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">専用アプリ利用で国内通話かけ放題</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>22円/30秒</strong><br>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">国内通話5分まで無料</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>22円/30秒</strong></td>
            <td><strong>22円/30秒</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">通話<br>オプション<br><strong>※1</strong></th>
            <td>5分かけ放題<br><strong>500円/月</strong><br>完全かけ放題<br><strong>1,480円/月</strong></td>
            <td>15分かけ放題<br><strong>1,100円/月</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">専用アプリ不要</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>かけ放題<br><strong>1,100円/月</strong></td>
            <td>5分/回以内<br>かけ放題<br><strong>550円/月</strong><br>通話定額<br><strong>1,650円/月</strong></td>
            <td>5分以内かけ放題<br><strong>550円/月</strong><br>通話かけ放題<br><strong>1,650円/月</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">データ追加</th>
            <td style="background-color:#ffffcc;"><strong>200円/1GB</strong></td>
            <td><strong>330円/1GB</strong></td>
            <td><strong>200円/1GB</strong></td>
            <td><strong>–</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB">
                    <li data-number="1">0GB～無制限まで従量課金</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>550円/1GB</strong></td>
            <td><strong>550円/1GB</strong></td>
            <td><strong>390円/1GB~</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">1・3・20・60GB<br>単位で追加可</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">SMS追加<br><strong>※2</strong></th>
            <td style="background-color:#ffffcc; border:3px solid #FFCD00;"><strong>50円/月</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">1GB～7GBのみ</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>154円/月</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">ドコモ回線のみ</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>–</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB">
                    <li data-number="1">月額基本料金に含まれる</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>–</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">月額基本料金に含まれる</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>–</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">月額基本料金に含まれる</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>–</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">月額基本料金に含まれる</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td><strong>–</strong>
                <ul class="list typeB" style="margin-top: 0.1rem;">
                    <li data-number="1">月額基本料金に含まれる</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="step" scope="col">
                <div class="text">データ定額<br>440プラン</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="text"><span class="linkTxt typeA"><a href="/domestic/service/vita" target="_blank"
                            class="bgBlue newWindow" rel="noopener noreferrer">ビタッ！<br>プラン</a></span></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="text"><span class="linkTxt typeA"><a href="/domestic/planlp_jiyujizai_super" target="_blank"
                            class="bgBlue newWindow" rel="noopener noreferrer">自由自在<br>プラン</a></span></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">Rakuten<br>最強プラン</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">ahamo</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">LINEMO</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="text">povo2.0</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-top:0; padding-top:0;">
            <th></th>
            <th class="step" scope="col">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <ul class="planFunctionIcon">
                    <li class="voice">音声通話</li>
                    <li class="data">データ</li>
                    <li class="sms">SMS</li>
                </ul>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

So I want to parse html for LLM to text like, see the `880円` part originally with `rowspan="2"` seperated into 2 row

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ～3GB  |        | **1,3  |        |        |        |        |        |
|        |        | 20円** |        |        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ～5GB  |        |        | **9    | **2,1  |        | **2,7  | **2,7  |
|        |        |        | 90円** | 78円** |        | 28円** | 00円** |
|        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
|        |        |        |        |        |        |        | -      |
|        |  880円 |        |        |        |        |        | 30日間 |
+--------|--------|--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ～7GB  |  880円 | **2,3  |        |        |        |        |        |
|        |        | 10円** |        |        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

How to do this ?